# Работа с файлами

Tags: php

Как на страницу вывести все, что есть, файлы с расширением .png из директории images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
foreach(glob(__DIR__ . '/images/*.png') as $value)
 print $value . "<br />\n";
```

То?